# Terminate/Close Last Activity

Tags: java, android

Can you show and explain me how to close the last activity/class that you open In Android.

I want my activity to close the last activity/class when he opens a new activity/class.

Answer (score 0):

whenever a new activity is being created, you must be starting it via Intent i.e. startactivity(intent)

Then, after startactivity(intent) add finish();

```
startactivity(intent);
finish();
```

Edit: if you want to close all of the existing activities and not just the current activity, also pass CLEAR_TOP flag in the intent

Comment: I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag to clear all the activities that remained open.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

For example:

Let's say you have A->B->C. So when you set the flag it will clear all activities on top of C

Comment: where should I put that heres an example

public void onButtonClick1(View v1) {
        if (v1.getId() == R.id.imageButton1) {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(CS_Category.this, CS_Assembly.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            


        }

Comment: @TyrellP.Zapanta Just look at your code compared to this answer... All you need is `i1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: I will input that code on every button or activity that would lunch right?

Comment: Yes as long as you want to close the last activity and any other one that remains open

Answer (score 0):

Whenever new activity start, that is TOP of stack.

finish() method is used to close the current or last activity.